# Can't find a high power linear power brick?

Tags: power, transformer

I've searched for quite a while, so I'm fairly sure I'm not doing things right. I need someone to point me in the right direction as I'm sure there's a better option.

I'm looking for a highish power (30V, 3A - preferably a little higher than this because I want it to go up to 30V) linear power brick for my power supply project. I've struggled to find one, so I assume I'm doing something wrong. Is this because such a high power will have high voltage losses over a wire?

I don't want a switching power supply as this will be a lab supply.

I generally wouldn't mind using an IEC connector and wiring a transformer myself, but I'm not completely sure enough of standards for isolated mains electrical supplies (of course this power supply has to be isolated).

I should probably add that I live in Australia, but that shouldn't change much, I can still buy stuff from ali express.

Comment: Why the requirement for a ***linear*** PSU?

Comment: http://www.digikey.com.au/product-search/en?x=0&y=0&lang=en&site=au&KeyWords=285-1815-ND

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just try googling "30V linear power supply schematic". One of the most promising hits was [this](http://www.learningelectronics.net/circuits/3-30v-3a-adjustable-regulated-dc-power.html): -

[image]
[image]

Circuits from other sources: -

[image]
[image]

There are plenty of designs out there. Google is your friend.

If in fact you are looking for a purchasing recommendation, your question will be closed.

Comment: I'm not looking for one, I'm asking if there is a better approach to buying a wall-wart as it doesn't seem as there are any.

Also, is that isolated from mains? I think I might have a misunderstanding on isolation. I thought that you're supposed to connect the secondary side to mains earth and then use an isolated transformer, maybe that isn't the case.

Comment: Well, it's either buy or build. With reinforced insulation, a ground is not required. Most wall-warts don't use a ground pin for this reason.

Comment: ah thanks, I think I know what I'm doing wrong.

the issue is that I didn't realise that to isolate it you just connect the gnd to the negative output of the bridge rectifier, that cleans up that issue nicely.

Comment: The transformer provides galvanic isolation up to several thousand volts (i.e. reinforced insulation). Earthing the DC secondary output is called grounding and can be needed to reduce noise or add protection when the transformer does not have full-spec insulation.